# Powershell-Add-ADGroupMember

Tags: powershell

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить менеджера группы рассылок (он же управляется(managedby)) в члены этой группы (members) или любой другой группы с помощью скрипта powershell. Можно просто через Add-ADGroupMember и указать конкретного управленца группой, но когда он поменяется, следующий управленец не добавится в группу. Поэтому хотелось бы сделать как то через переменную. Спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавить Менеджера группы (managedby) в Члены группы (members) с помощью powershell